# Character Sprint Spaghetti Code

Tags: beginner, classes, actionscript-3

I finally managed to get the code to work properly. It makes the player object move faster if the user double taps the arrow key with a few 'ticks' (new frames) after the 1st stroke. - User presses and has a limited time to press again to sprint the object. If the time runs out the user has to try again.

However, It'd be better I believe to be working with time, miliseconds and not 'ticks', as what I intend involves lots of key combinations that have x seconds to be pressed.

I would like to know the redundancies in the code, what can be made into a class and something better then screen refresh to time things up (delays?).

```
package 
{

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

public class Main extends Sprite {
var keys:Array = [];
var player:Sprite = new Sprite();   
var sprint, condition1, condition2, timerStart, keyUp, keyDown:Boolean;
var timer:int;

public function Main():void {

player.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
player.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 25);
player.graphics.endFill;

addChild(player);
player.x = 100;
player.y = 250;

player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);
}

function update(e:Event):void {

  if ((timerStart)&&(timer>0)) {
    timer --;
    condition1 = true;
  }

  if (keyUp) {
    if ((condition1) && (timer > 0)) {
       condition2 = true;
    }   

    if (sprint) {
      timerStart = false;
      condition1 = false;
      condition2 = false;
      sprint = false;
      timer = 7;
    }

    if (timer <= 0) {
      timerStart = false;
      condition1 = false;
      condition2 = false;
      sprint = false;
      timer = 7;
    }
}


if (keys[Keyboard.RIGHT]) {
timerStart = true;

if ((condition1) && (condition2)) {
sprint = true;
}

if (sprint) {
player.x += 7;
} else player.x += 2;
            }

function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
keys[e.keyCode] = true;
keyUp = false;
keyDown = true;
}

function onKeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
keys[e.keyCode] = false;
keyUp = true;
keyDown = false;
}

} // class
} // package
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a once over

- Indentation is terrible, consider using a tool like [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org), it works for ActionScript as well
- Keep working with `Event.ENTER_FRAME` <- It is the better approach in my mind
- Always be on the look out for copy pasted code, this:

  ```
  if (sprint) {
    timerStart = false;
    condition1 = false;
    condition2 = false;
    sprint = false;
    timer = 7;
  }

  if (timer <= 0) {
    timerStart = false;
    condition1 = false;
    condition2 = false;
    sprint = false;
    timer = 7;
  }
  ```

could be

```
    if (sprint || timer <= 0) {
      timerStart = false;
      condition1 = false;
      condition2 = false;
      sprint = false;
      timer = 7;
    }
```

- Do not track `keyDown`, you do not use it, and it's value is always the opposite of `keyUp`
- `condition1` and `condition2` are very unfortunate names, you should try to be more descriptive
- This code could use some well named constants and indenting:

  ```
  if (sprint) {
  player.x += 7;
  } else player.x += 2;
  ```

  I would rather see

  ```
  var FAST_SPEED = 7,
      NORMAL_SPEED = 2;
  if (isSprinting) {
      player.x += FAST_SPEED;
  } else {
      player.x += NORMAL_SPEED;
  }
  ```

  or if I wanted to be fancy

  ```
  player.x += isSprinting ? FAST_SPEED : NORMAL_SPEED;
  ```

Comment: Ok, how do I time things if needed? 0,5 secs instead of the value 7 held by var timer for an example :P

Comment: That would be an SO question :\